# Uncertainty of angle with known uncertainty of cosine of angle

Tags: error-analysis, statistics, experimental-technique

Quick question, how do I proceed if I managed to get (from some kind of a measurement) the value of $\cos(\phi)$ and its error $\sigma_{\cos\phi}$ and I'd like to find $\phi \pm \sigma_{\phi}$?

Would it be reasonable to just calculate $\arccos(\cos(\phi) \pm \sigma_{\cos\phi})$ to find the range the angle is likely in? Can I somehow use the error propagation formula to get the error directly? Or is there any other way this is commonly dealt with? Thank you.

Comment: Errors can be quite complicated to deal with, the way you suggested is quite good and less likely to give a wrong answer than other mathematical ways

Comment: Google "error propagation" for something more general than just a function but entire equations. Involves derivatives and junk. https://www.geol.lsu.edu/jlorenzo/geophysics/uncertainties/Uncertaintiespart2.html

Answer (score 2):

So you have the measurements in the form $cos\phi\pm \Delta(cos\phi)$ and need to find $\phi\pm\Delta\phi$

Note that $$\left| \frac{\Delta cos(\phi)}{\Delta\phi}\right|=sin(\phi)$$ where we assume $\{\phi\ne 0^\circ, 90^\circ\}$ so that $$\mid\Delta cos(\phi)\mid=sin(\phi)\Delta\phi$$ From what you say, it looks like you have a value for $\Delta cos(\phi)=\sigma_{\cos\phi}$

So the uncertainty in $\phi$  $$\Delta\phi=\frac{\sigma_{\cos\phi}}{sin(\phi)}$$ meaning you would write the range as $\phi\pm\Delta\phi$

---

As per a comment made by Mark H. for very small angles, the computed uncertainty will be large (since the the expression for $\Delta\phi$ becomes large if the denominator approaches zero) so an additional term to the $|\Delta \cos(\phi )|$ expression is added so that we now have the equation (Taylor series expansion about $\phi\approx 0$ - second term is the second derivative of original $cos$ term)  $$|\Delta\cos\phi| \approx \sin\phi\Delta\phi + \frac{1}{2}\cos\phi(\Delta\phi)^2$$ so that for small angles, i.e., $cos(\phi)\approx 1$, the quadratic term dominates.

Comment: I think it would be a good idea to say what to do when $\cos\phi \approx \pm 1$ since the current formulas result in unbounded uncertainty in $\phi$.

Comment: That's actually a good point. If $\phi\rightarrow 0$ the RHS of the $\Delta \phi$ expression approaches $\infty$.

Comment: I don't think your edit is enough. If the calculated $\phi$ is 0.01, then the error is $100\sigma_{\cos\phi}$. I think you need to use a second-degree error expression: $|\Delta\cos\phi| \approx |\sin\phi\Delta\phi| + |\frac{1}{2}\cos\phi(\Delta\phi)^2|$. The second term will dominate when $\cos\phi$ is near 1.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that while I was doing the last edit. I guess I should add that too but as a footnote. thx.

Answer (score 1):

Let $y = f(x)$ be a function of $x$.  Let $S_x$ be the standard deviation for $x$.  The standard deviation for $S_y$ for $y$ is $\sqrt{({\partial f \over \partial x})^2 S_x^2}$.  [See, for example, the text Data Analysis for Scientists and Engineers by Meyer.]

Let $x$ be $\theta$ and $y = cos(\theta)$.  $S_{cos(\theta)} = \sqrt{S_{\theta}^2 \space sin^2(\theta)}$; so $S_{\theta} = {S_{cos(\theta)} \over |sin(\theta)|}$.

The other answers address small $\theta$.

Comment: Standard deviation is $\sigma$. The symbol $S$ is more appropriately named standard uncertainty.

Comment: Good comment. I need to clarify the nomenclature: S denotes the standard deviation of the sample (known). I reserve σ to denote the standard deviation of the population (unknown).  S is an approximation to σ.  This is the convention used in the reference I provided; the nomenclature is not consistent in the literature.  If you knew σ, I would replace S with σ.  Also, the final result could be expressed as (an estimate of) the mean and (an estimate of) the standard deviation of the mean, which is different from the (estimate of) the standard deviation of the population as given in the answer.

Comment: I've always heard/assumed that $\sigma$ is the infinite population value and $S$ (or $S_M$) is the finite population value. I would have to look back at the Guide for Uncertainty on Measurements (GUM) to nail down the terminology again.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, for small errors, the derivative is an approximation of the ratio of the dependent variable's error to the independent variable's error. Since the derivative of $\cos$ is $\sin$, that gives us that $\frac{\sigma_{\cos \phi}}{\sigma _{\phi}}=\sin\phi$. Rearranging gives $\sigma_{ \phi} =\frac{ \sigma_{\cos\phi}}{\sin \phi }$.

As Mark H points out in a comment to another answer, this goes to infinity as $\sin \phi$ goes to zero. Looking at a graph of $\cos$, you can see that near $\phi =0$, the curve is close to horizontal, meaning that small variations in $\cos \phi$ correspond to large variations in $\phi$. Your idea of taking $\arccos$ would also be problematic in this region, as $\cos$ is not 1-1 in the neighborhood around $0$.

However, $\cos \phi$ can, in the neighborhood around $0$, be approximated by $1-\frac{\phi^2}2$, thus giving $\phi = \pm \sqrt {2-2\cos \phi}$, so for $\cos \phi$ close to zero, you can plug $\cos \phi \pm\sigma_{\cos \phi}$ into that formula. With two $\pm$ (a \pm in the value to plug into the formula *and* a \pm in the formula), that will give you four different values, and you should take the widest spread.

And all of this, of course, applies only to small $\sigma_{\cos \phi}$.